# Why the main festivals are in chaturmas if god is sleeping in that period?

Tags: gods, festivals

Ok, this might be very silly question but i couldn't find answer from my elders, I thought this could be right place to get my answer.

I know the scientific reason that in the rainy or monsoon season, for good health, we can do Upavas and other Vratas.

But what could be possibly reason, If god does sleep on Devashayani Ekadashi and wakes up on DevUthi Ekadashi, why does our all main festivals like Ganesh Chaturthi, Diwali, Navaratri lie in these four months ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Lord Vishnu help his devotees when He goes to deep sleep especially during the time of Chaturmas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19728/3500)

Comment: He does not "sleep" where he loses consciousness of the world. It is more a "turning inwards" and observing the jeeva's activities. It is an impetus for the jeeva koti also to turn inwards and hence the various structural and functional systems like the poojas and vratas to aid this introspection and pursuit of the divine.